# Scanner inside method dont ask for input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I ask user to insert an `item name with extension ".txt"` and if the `item name` is coresponding to the `existing itemName.txt` then  user need to insert the `location name with extension ".txt"` where he want to "transfer" it .
if everithing is ok then the content from `itemName.txt`  will be writen into the `locationName.txt`

My Main looks like this :

```
package victor;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main extends Item {
    public Main(String location, Integer length, Integer height, Integer depth) {
        super(location, length, height, depth);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Location> locationList = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("Welcome to create new:");
        System.out.println("Please follow the steps:");
        HashMap<Integer, String> menu = new HashMap<>();
        menu.put(1, "Create Location");
        menu.put(2, "Create Item");
        menu.put(3, "Transfer to location");
        menu.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + "- " + value));
        int user_choice;
        Scanner userInputMenu = new Scanner(System.in);
        user_choice = userInputMenu.nextInt();
        switch (user_choice) {
            case 1:
                createLocationPlusFile(locationList);
            case 2:
                createItemPlusFile(itemList);
            case 3:
                transferItemToLocation(itemList, locationList);
        }
    }
}
```

When user input  from menu  -  `3`    , program is closing `Process finished with exit code 0`.

Here is my  Item Class  with the method I wrote:

```
package victor;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Item extends Location {
    private String itemName;
    private Integer kg;
    private Integer length;
    private Integer height;
    private Integer depth;

    public Item(String itemName, Integer kg, Integer length, Integer height, Integer depth) {
        super();
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.kg = kg;
        this.length = length;
        this.height = height;
        this.depth = depth;
    }


    public Item() {

    }

    public Item(String location, Integer length, Integer height, Integer depth) {
        super();
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    public Integer getKg() {
        return kg;
    }

    public void setKg(Integer kg) {
        this.kg = kg;
    }

    public Integer getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public void setLength(Integer length) {
        this.length = length;
    }

    public Integer getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(Integer height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public Integer getDepth() {
        return depth;
    }

    public void setDepth(Integer depth) {
        this.depth = depth;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item{" +
                "itemName='" + itemName + '\'' +
                ", kg=" + kg +
                ", length=" + length +
                ", height=" + height +
                ", depth=" + depth +
                '}';
    }

    public static void createItemPlusFile(List<Item> itemList) throws NullPointerException, IOException {
        int defaultLength = 80;
        int defaultHeight = 205;
        int defaultDepth = 120;
        int defaultKg = 3500;
        Scanner in1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Item Name: ");
        String itemName = in1.nextLine();
        System.out.println("New Item created successfully!" + "\n" + itemName);


        int inLength;
        Scanner in2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Item height: ");
        int itemLength = in2.nextInt();
        if (itemLength > defaultLength) {
            System.out.println("Height that you added is to big, please use a height of max  205");
            inLength = in2.nextInt();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Height inserted correctly! ");
        }


        int inHeight;
        Scanner in3 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Item height: ");
        int itemHeight = in3.nextInt();
        if (itemHeight > defaultHeight) {
            System.out.println("Height that you added is to big, please use a height of max  205");
            inHeight = in3.nextInt();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Height inserted correctly! ");
        }
        int inDepth;
        Scanner in4 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Item depth: ");
        int itemDepth = in4.nextInt();
        if (itemDepth > defaultDepth) {
            System.out.println("Depth that you added is to big, please use a depth of max  120");
            inDepth = in4.nextInt();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Depth inserted correctly! ");
        }
        int inKg;
        Scanner in5 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Item kg: ");
        int itemKg = in4.nextInt();
        if (itemKg > defaultKg) {
            System.out.println("kg that you added is to big, please use a depth of max  3500");
            inDepth = in4.nextInt();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Kg inserted correctly! ");
        }
        Item item = new Item(itemName, itemKg, itemLength, itemHeight, itemDepth);
        File file = new File(item.getItemName() + "CUSCAS001GRY-uk.txt");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(item.getItemName() + "CUSCAS001GRY-uk.txt", true);
        fileWriter.write(item + "\n");
        fileWriter.close();
    }
//this method I wrote, I expect to ask user to input the item and if item with this name exist then he insert the location where he want to "transfer" it .
       public static void transferItemToLocation(List<Item> itemList, List<Location> locationList) throws IOException {
    for (Item item : itemList) {
        for (Location location : locationList) {
            Scanner inputItemTransfer = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Insert the item you want to transfer + .txt  extension!");
            inputItemTransfer.nextLine();
            if (inputItemTransfer.nextLine()
                    .equalsIgnoreCase(item + ".txt")) {
                Scanner inputTransferToLocation = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Insert the location where you want to transfer the item");
                inputTransferToLocation.nextLine();
                if (inputTransferToLocation.nextLine()
                        .equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(location))) {
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(String.valueOf(inputItemTransfer)));
                    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(inputTransferToLocation + ".txt", true);
                    BufferedWriter outputStream = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
                    String str;
                    while ((str = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        outputStream.write(str + "\n");
                    }
                    outputStream.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I assume that I do something wrong with the scanner .
Any help/critics are totaly appreciated

Comment: Unrelated: `throws NullpointerException` is meaningless, you do not need to declare any RuntimeException on the signature. And hint: do not catch NullPointerExceptions either. They are BUGs. When they occur: fix them immediately.

Comment: And please see [mcve]. Try to reduce your input the absolute minimum that still shows the problem. That most likely will enable you to figure the bug yourself. That is what learning programming is about, too: reducing your code to figure what exactly causes issues. When you know the WHAT, the fix is most often trivial.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: @GhostCat  Sorry for that , I forrgot to remove it  from there :) and  ofcourse you are right regarding that xD

Comment: I don't know if it's related but you create many Scanner and never close them

Comment: @T.K  I tried also that but it see;s is not the couse , I think is because  my  `itemList` and `locationlist`  are empty  so  I will try to create  some items and locations and use that on base to create files for each and then write from one to another  to see if that works :)

Comment: You don't need to create a new `Scanner` each time you ask the user to enter a value. You ask the user to enter so many details that your application would probably be better as a [GUI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm) application rather than a console application.

Comment: @Abra , My ideea was to create an item as  .txt   and then based on what is inside the file to "transfer" that to a location  .txt  , but  now I will use a different approche , I will create a list of items and locations and based on that I will  create files and write from one to another :)

Comment: @Abra  At the moment I just wanted to transfer "item" inside the "location" , then further i will use the  dimensions to see if item fit inside the location or not , I mean this is what I have in my head right now

Comment: When the user selects option 3 the program will invoke `transferItemToLocation(itemList, locationList);`.  When it returns from that method it will exit because there are no subsequence commands.  You did not include the code for that method so its unknown what it is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a Scanner object for every prompt where the User needs to input data. One Scanner object for the entire application will do just fine. Just declare the object as ***public static*** within the **Main** class, for example:

```
public class Main extends Item {
    
    // Declare a Scanner object that can potentially be used anywhere.
    public static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\R");


    public Main(String location, Integer length, Integer height, Integer depth) {
        super(location, length, height, depth);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // ... main() method code here ...
    }
}
```

Then everywhere you have a prompt to the User and need to use a Scanner method to get input, use **Main.userInput.** instead, for example:

```
user_choice = Main.userInput.nextInt();
```

or:

```
String itemName = Main.userInput.nextLine();
```

When using **Scanner#nextInt()** (or any Scanner#nextXXX methods) and a Scanner#nextLine() prompt will directly follow then you will most likely need to consume the *newline* character from when the enter key is hit from the Scanner#nextInt() use. The `nextInt()` method does not consume the newline character like the `nextline()` method does and therefore the prompt using the `nextLine()` method appears to be skipped. In cases like this you would want to do:

```
user_choice = Main.userInput.nextInt();
Main.userInput.nextLine();
```

A good rule of thumb is:

If you use the **Scanner#nextLine()** method, then use it for **everything** otherwise, don't use it at all. Use the `next()` and `nextXXX()` methods instead.

If you create your Scanner as shown above (with the `useDelimiter("\\R")` method) then the `Scanner#next()` method will return that similar to what the `Scanner#nextLine()` method would return.

---

Currently, your `transferItemToLocation()` method is double prompting for each prompt within the method because of the way you are using the Scanner methods.

```
public static void transferItemToLocation(List<Item> itemList, List<Location> locationList) throws IOException {
    for (Item item : itemList) {
        for (Location location : locationList) {
            Scanner inputItemTransfer = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Insert the item you want to transfer + .txt  extension!");
            inputItemTransfer.nextLine();
            if (inputItemTransfer.nextLine()
                    .equalsIgnoreCase(item + ".txt")) {
                Scanner inputTransferToLocation = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Insert the location where you want to transfer the item");
                inputTransferToLocation.nextLine();
                if (inputTransferToLocation.nextLine()
                        .equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(location))) {
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(String.valueOf(inputItemTransfer)));
                    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(inputTransferToLocation + ".txt", true);
                    BufferedWriter outputStream = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
                    String str;
                    while ((str = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        outputStream.write(str + "\n");
                    }
                    outputStream.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can only assume why you are doing this because you have not provided all your code which is partially why I posted a lot of the drivel about Scanner above. What you've got here is not going to work the way you think it will. As mentioned earlier, get rid of all those Scanner objects and use something similar to what is declared within the **Main** class (similar to what is shown at the beginning of this post). Declare String variables named **inputItemTransfer** and **inputTransferToLocation**. Place the User input into those variables respectively for each prompt and use the data contained within those variables rather than the Scanner objects, for example:

```
public static void transferItemToLocation(List<Item> itemList, List<Location> locationList) throws IOException {
    String inputItemTransfer;
    String inputTransferToLocation;
    for (Item item : itemList) {
        for (Location location : locationList) {
            System.out.println("Insert the item you want to transfer + .txt  extension!");
            inputItemTransfer = Main.userInput.nextLine();
            if (inputItemTransfer.equalsIgnoreCase(item + ".txt")) {
                System.out.println("Insert the location where you want to transfer the item");
                inputTransferToLocation = Main.userInput.nextLine();
                if (inputTransferToLocation.equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(location))) {
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(String.valueOf(inputItemTransfer)));
                    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(inputTransferToLocation + ".txt", true);
                    BufferedWriter outputStream = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
                    String str;
                    while ((str = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        outputStream.write(str + "\n");
                    }
                    outputStream.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whether this method is now going to function properly is honestly beyond me. Without all the code or at least a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's hard to say. One step at a time I suppose.

---

**On a side:**

As mentioned in Comments, it does indeed appear that there is a lot of required data entry by a User to utilize your application which is sort of a downer and actually difficult for some. Perhaps consider a more **menu based** system to reduce entry requirements and make usage a more comfortable experience.

---

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for the time you took to explain to me this stuff ,  is really  helpfull .I did  my method again and  now it seems just  fine  xd. Regarding the menu :  I a,  reproduceing the same  ,enu i have at my  work place , to transfer  the items  to location   kind of , so that is the reason ,  later on i  will look for  better inprovments ,  also  I will create different metods while i ask user to do  transfer ,  perhaps  aparth method for input item  and  another one for transfer to location  or something similar .  Sorry  if  my explanation is not perfer :(. Thank you again :)